Camera initial position problem in PLAY mode
I would like help in that I have a prefab camera with these transform.position data:
Scene:Vector3(-2.86999989,1.01999998,-0.810000002).

This row in the code:
[SerializeField] private Vector3 initialCameraPosition = new Vector3(-2.86999989, 1.01999998, -0.810000002);

I wrote a script that allows me to start my camera rotation with these initial transform.position data. However, when I start the script, the prefab (camera) transform.position values ​​are immediately overwritten:
play:Vector3(-2.72023177,0.810079217,-1.23373544).

The difference between Scene and Play transform.position data:
X axis: 0.1498
Y axis: -0.2099
Z axis: -0.4237

The Target on which I drag the script has Vector3(0,0,0,) transform.position.

I use only 1 camera.;

Other scripts doesn’t use the camera.;

There are no other settings affecting on the camera.


My question is why does the initial value of my camera jump/change in PLAY mode?
Thank you in advance for your help.
The script:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Transform target; 
    [SerializeField] private Vector3 initialCameraPosition = new Vector3(3f, 1f, 2.5f);
    [SerializeField] private Vector3 initialCameraRotation = new Vector3(30f, 45f, 0f);

    public float sensitivity = 100f; // Forgatás érzékenysége
    private float _yaw = 0f;         // Az aktuális forgási szög vízszintes tengelyen
    private float _pitch = 0f;       // Az aktuális forgási szög függőleges tengelyen

    private float minPitch = 5f;     // Minimális függőleges szög
    private float maxPitch = 90f;    // Maximális függőleges szög

    private Transform cameraObject;  // A kamera objektum, amit dinamikusan megkeresünk

    void Start()
    {
        // Kamera objektum megkeresése, ha nincs előzőleg hozzárendelve
        cameraObject = Camera.main.transform;

        if (target == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Nincs célpont (Target) hozzárendelve!");
        }

        if (cameraObject == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Nincs kamera a jelenetben!");
            return;
        }

        // Beállítjuk a kezdeti pozíciót és rotációt
        cameraObject.position = initialCameraPosition;
        cameraObject.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(initialCameraRotation);

        // Távolság és forgási szögek kiszámítása a megadott kezdőpozícióból
        Vector3 targetDirection = cameraObject.position - target.position;
        distanceFromTarget = targetDirection.magnitude;

        _yaw = initialCameraRotation.y; // A yaw értéke a kezdeti rotációból
        _pitch = initialCameraRotation.x; // A pitch értéke a kezdeti rotációból
    }

    void Update()
    {
        HandleInput();

        // Korlátozzuk a pitch értéket
        _pitch = Mathf.Clamp(_pitch, minPitch, maxPitch);

        // Forgatjuk a kamerát a célpont körül
        RotateCamera();
    }

    private void HandleInput()
    {
        Vector2 inputDelta = Vector2.zero;

        // Mobil érintés
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            inputDelta = touch.deltaPosition;
        }
        // Egér
        else if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            inputDelta = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"), Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"));
        }

        // Frissítjük a forgási értékeket
        _yaw += inputDelta.x * sensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
        _pitch -= inputDelta.y * sensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    private void RotateCamera()
    {
        // Kiszámítjuk a forgást a célpont körül
        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(_pitch, _yaw, 0f);
        Vector3 positionOffset = rotation * new Vector3(0, 0, -distanceFromTarget);

        // Beállítjuk a kamera pozícióját és rotációját
        cameraObject.position = target.position + positionOffset;
        cameraObject.LookAt(target);
    }
}


does it move if you take off this script? what is the content of distanceFromTarget

Yes it moves after taking off the script, but it works also just the camera position slightly changes and it doesn't look good after pressing the PLAY button. The distanceFromTarget was removed from the script.

if it moves despite removing this script - you need to find the other thing somehow effecting the camera, so, is it childed to anything?

The distanceFromTarget was removed from the script. no it wasn't .. at least not in your code here - you removed the class field but not the usages so now it wouldn't compile at all

I'd claim because the initialCameraPosition is conflicting with the initialCameraRotation.
The initial position is completely overwritten by the latter and the rest of the code is purely driven by the distance and orientation.
In fact the initial position almost doesn't matter at all - except for calculating the distanceFromTarget.
In this kind of orbit camera setup you can not control both initial position and pitch, yaw at the same time. You have to decide for one of these and currently the initialCameraRotation is the one that wins.

Thank you Hugo for your editing!
These are the transform data which have been settled on the Main Camera:
initialCameraPosition: Vector3(-2.86999989,1.01999998,-0.810000002);
initialCameraRotation: Vector3(30.3649998,49.6150017,0);
These should be the starting point for the Camera. But it is overwritten after pushing PLAY button.

As said already: The rotation overrules the initial position. If it doesn't match exactly the required values to match with the initial position it will always be different. The initial position is only used to calculate the distanceFromTarget ...

Sorry, maybe it's me or it's unclear, but as long as you don't touch the screen, what kind of rotation overwrites the initial value? If I start the game and do not touch the mouse or the mobile screen, then the scene/screen should remain the initial camera position, which is the camera's prefab position.

No because regardless of any touch your setting for initialRotation will overwrite the pitch and yaw and also without any interaction it is only the current pitch and yaw that matters and will overwrite the camera's position every frame in  cameraObject.position = target.position + positionOffset; which is purely based on the rotation which is initially set by initialRotation .. the initial position is completely ignored in that calculation .. as said it only matters for the distance from target

As said in an orbit camera you either want to provide an initial rotation OR and initial position .. both is at best redundant or - like in your case - conflicting
